# Git repository suddenly isn't updated anymore even though it commits/pushes ok on Android Studio side

Tags: android, github, version-control

This all worked very smoothly up to now i.e. I have 2 years worth of git updates from this app. Everything looks fine on the AS side i.e. commit/push works fine and it says 'x files commited'. I recently checked my github page directly and to my surprise I didn't see any update for the last 2 months even though I just did 2.

AS shows this i.e. the blue checkmarks show just fine on git, but the 2 red 'x' are not showing: (what is the difference between origin/master vs. master ?)

[image: AS Log]

on the git side I do see this:

[image: Git repository]

when I click on the following button:

[image: Git web link]

it yields a 404 page on git, the blue checkmarks are yielding correct URLs

So something broke and I'm pretty sure I'm the culprit (I had to hack around lots
of files due to very frustrating compile issue. (I spare you those details)

Now, what are my options?

- Does anybody know what happened here and what files might be affected and how it can be fixed?
- I would prefer not to lose the history etc. of this project and start over on Git, can I somehow 'reconnect' ?
- Worst case, if I decide to restart, can I at least not touch anything on the AS side and just start something new on github (do I have to delete the repository or just rename etc.)

Hope I explained this correctly ...

---

P.S> showing my ignorance on git, barely got this going, so I need to refresh a bit ...

I see a 'branch', but it only shows 'master':

[image: git branch]

also when I click on the branch icon, it shows this, not sure if that helps, but thanks for the pointer, will check more tomorrow

[image: branch]

---

2nd PS: git status shows:

```html
C:\Users\roberts\AndroidStudioProjects\LingoFlash>git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   .idea/caches/build_file_checksums.ser
        modified:   .idea/misc.xml

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .idea/caches/gradle_models.ser

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

and then this !!!

```html
C:\Users\roberts\AndroidStudioProjects\LingoFlash>git push
fatal: AggregateException encountered.
   One or more errors occurred.
Username ---
Password ---
Counting objects: 46, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (37/37), done.
Writing objects: 100% (46/46), 6.21 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 46 (delta 30), reused 0 (delta 0)

remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (30/30), completed with 21 local objects.
To https://github.com/---
   eb29877..ff09500  master -> master
```

it seems to have fixed the issue and flushed the 'pipe', thanks so much !

[image: updated git history]

Comment: I believe you have made another branch and started committing your project in that one instead of the original one. If I were you I will check my repository for any extra branches or issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is the difference between origin/master vs. master ?

`origin/master` records the last time the remote repository branch master was updated (through push or fetch)

`master` is a local branch, which does not seem to have been pushed (or origin/master would have been updated to that same commit)

You can try and switch to a command-line session, checking out the output of `git status`, and `git push`.

Comment: @Mairyu Well done! Pay attention to your git status: any untracked or modified file is not pushed, and remain local to your repo.

Comment: thanks, I still have to fix something since with the latest upload the origin/master vs. master are again out of sync it seems, but at least now I know where to look